# Add a variable in preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to add a variable in preg_replace.

for Ex :-

In this blelow line of code, I want to add $text instead of "sometext"

```
$text = "sometext";
$lineOfValue = preg_replace("/.*sometext[\"', ]*/", "", $line);
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: `$lineOfValue = preg_replace("/.*$text[\"', ]*/", "", $line);` Where is the problem?!

Comment: Getting this error when adding like your reply : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpresstest\write.php on line 12

Comment: Then just concatenate it: `$lineOfValue = preg_replace("/.*" . $text . "[\"', ]*/", "", $line);` ?!

Comment: If the contents of `$text` is guaranteed to be safe for use in the expression you can use `"/.*{$text}[\"', ]*/"` as well, wrapping the variable references in curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

In a regular expression the $ symbol signifies the end of the string being processed, therefore including a variable within a regular expression as suggested by @Rizier123 won't work.

Instead the variable should be concatenated into the regular expression as follows to avoid the $ being misinterpreted:

```
$text = 'sometext';
$lineOfValue = preg_replace("/.*" . $text . "[\"', ]*/", "", $line);
```

Also - if your $text variable may contain any character, you should consider using [preg_quote()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to make the string safe for use within a regular expression:

```
$text = 'sometext';
$lineOfValue = preg_replace("/.*" . preg_quote($text, '/') . "[\"', ]*/", "", $line);
```

Comment: The expression delimiter should also be escaped.

Comment: Good call - I've edited the example to show the use of preg_quote()'s optional second parameter